# PHP/Apache - Sessions not sticking

Tags: php, apache, session, mod-rewrite

I am using Apache 2.4.4 and PHP 5.4.14, on Windows 7 (x64). The issue I have is that php sessions do not stick. This happened with Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.4.4 too, updated yesterday hoping it was only a bad setting in `php.ini`, yet nothing changed.

In chrome, session id's change for every page, only if I use rewrite rules. When using rewrite rules the cookies `path` oddly changes to `/pages_name/` instead of remaining `/`.

In opera, session id's change even if I refresh the page. So does in IE.

In both cases the cookies are accepted by the browsers.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&info1=$2&info2=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&info1=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

After searching i came across some "solutions" none of which worked

Session save path is working, files are being writen. Using default session handler.

Setting `session.cookie_path` to `/`

Setting `session.cookie_lifetime` to other then `0`

I am not using `session_regenerate_id`

`session_start( );` is the first line of code on all pages

If more information is needed I will update this post, thank you.

---

On further research it turns out to be an issue with the `RewriteRule`s, no idea how to fix it yet.

Also the cookies from `session_start( )` are set to `localhost/home/` as if, it was a folder yet it's a variable `localhost/index.php?page=home`. Because of this every page gets its own `session id`, any ideas for a fix?

Comment: Have you checked the path where the session files are being written?  Are there more and more files being created with every request, or none at all?  (Assuming you are using the default session handler).

Comment: forgot to mention that, yes the path is good and more and more files being created with every request. I am using the default session handler.

Comment: Does there happen to be session information passed in the URL? Like in the query string?

Comment: no, and `session.use_trans_sid` is `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of starting a new session by `session_start();`, first check if browser already sent current session_id.

```
if (isset($_POST['session_id'])) {
    $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] = $_POST['session_id'];
    session_start();
} else {
    session_start();
}
```

If that does not work, then your PHP and/or Apache configuration seems to be broken.
Why don't you try default configs?

Comment: I am not setting the cookies myself and let php do it, using that gives me `Undefined index: session_id`

Comment: For the code in this answer to work the first line should be `if (isset($_POST['session_id'])) {`  (the change being addition of `isset(...)`)

Comment: @MPKaboose: Your PHP and/or Apache configuration seems to be broken. Why don't you try default configs?

Comment: after doing so I found that `mod_rewrite` is causing the issue when turned on, when not the site behaves as it should (and not using clean URLs)